# How to decode unexpected strings from users?

Tags: encode

I've published an app, and I find some of the comments to be like this: `&amp;ETH;&amp;nbsp;&amp;ETH;&amp;micro;&amp;ETH;&amp;ordm;&amp;ETH;&amp;deg;&amp;ETH;&amp;frac14;&amp;ETH;&amp;micro;&amp;ETH;&amp;acute;&amp;Ntilde;`

I have googled a lot and I cannot decode it so that the comment will not be shown this way. This is the way it is stored in database; it can be in Cyrillic, but I could not decode it as well. Any clue on how to understand this kind of comments?

Comment: It was probably doubly HTML encoded. When decoding it twice using https://mothereff.in/html-entities the result is `Ð ÐµÐºÐ°Ð¼ÐµÐ´Ñ`. That *could* be botched Unicode data

Comment: and how come a simple user could write that from his mobile phone?

Comment: This is not what users have typed in, this is how your input form has screwed it. You need to find and fix the bug, not 'decode' the accidental garbage.

Comment: It could be that they are entering comments say in UTF-8, but in a non-western character set. Then probably a silly, misguided server-side "sanitation" routine garbles the data.

Comment: Mismatched text encoding somewhere in your pipeline -- the user didn't botch it up.

Comment: the thing is that other comments are fine. what could this user type so that the output is this?

Comment: `what could this user type so that the output is this?` هذا، على سبيل المثال

Comment: లేదా ఈ! ఏ ఆలోచన లాంగ్వేజ్గా ఉంది

Comment: Anything at all, in a locale or language that uses a different text encoding than you're set up for.      (When in doubt, just UTF-8 everything; these days  that'll get you 90% of the way there at least)

Comment: thank you guys. The problem was with Russian language input. It would be great if any of you can post a formatted answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These appear to be doubly encoded HTML entities. So for example, `&` was turned to `&amp;` and that was then again turned to  `&amp;amp;`

When decoding the data twice using [this online tool](http://mothereff.in/html-entities) (there are many others)  the result is

> Ð ÐµÐºÐ°Ð¼ÐµÐ´Ñ

That could be Unicode data, e.g. UTF-8 in a non-western character set like Cyrillic or Arabic, that

1. was misinterpreted as single-byte input
2. was garbled by a misguided "sanitation" method, possibly a call or two to PHP's [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities) (which incidentally assumes the single-byte ISO-8859-1 encoding by default in older versions, so a call to this function could be the whole source of the problem).

The fix will likely need to be on server side.

If you are using PHP, see [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) for a handy guide.